# Is it possible for an application to have a different name for each supported language?

Tags: qt

I have an application that supports English and French. My clients would like the name of the application (i.e. the text that shows up underneath the icon) to be "Friend" if the user's system language is English, and "Ami" if the user's system language is French (made-up names to illustrate the point), and to have this displayed application name change dynamically whenever the user changes the language setting (as opposed to maybe installing it with a different name based on the current language setting).

Is this possible, or is the name of the application pretty much fixed regardless of the system language?

Comment: For which OS? It is part of the build settings for the app and thus it changes depending on the target os. For windows it is done with locale specific string tables (IIRC).

Comment: @ErikMan: it's for Mac and Windows.

Comment: Whilst it will be possible, I don't expect Qt will do this for you, so you'll have to use native code for each platform. It's a rather strange request, as a name is not usually translated. For Mac, the name comes from the plist in the app bundle, and is registered with [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html), so looking at that may be a good place to start.